# Width percentages not working with div

Tags: html, css, width

Trying to get two divs to position each other side by side in a container div, but they will not follow `width` attributes so I can't get the next to each other. I've tried to use solutions from other questions but none of them have worked.

```css
.intro-container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: #fdee58;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.intro-container-text {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  float: left;
}

.intro-containter-img {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #00ffff;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-container">
  <div class="into-container-text"></div>
  <div class="intro-container-img"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Typos in `into-container-text` and `intro-containter-img `. Also, your divs have no height or content, so they collapse. Fix your typos and give the divs some content or height and it works fine.

Comment: @j08691 I actually can't believe I could't see that! Thanks for pointing out the typos, I should really check my code more carefully.

Comment: you also have mistake in `intro-containter-img` class `intro-container-img`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistaken typo in your class attribute.

```
<div class="into-container-text"></div>
```

Instead, tt should be

```
<div class="intro-container-text"></div>
```

And don't forget to have a div element to clear the floats, this is important to avoid layout problem that arise due to float: left property.

```
<div class="intro-container">
  <div class="intro-container-text"></div>
  <div class="intro-container-img"></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I didn't see the typos, but I also didn't know about the `clear` div practice.

Comment: Its good you noticed it. And yes, clear is a must have thing when you are using float property for div elements.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you mispelled "intro-container-text"... in your html is "into-container-text" and in css "intro-container-text";

Second you just need to say to the parent that you want the childs to display in line with `display:flex;`and then you can remove the float.

```
<div class="intro-container">
<div class="intro-container-text"></div>
<div class="intro-container-img"></div>
</div>

.intro-container {
  display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    background-color: #fdee58;
}
.intro-container-text {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.intro-container-img {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #00ffff;
}
```

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39zmf9vw/7/) for you.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the naming in the class again.

```css
.intro-container{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    background-color: #fdee58;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.intro-container-text{
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    float: left;
}
.intro-container-img{
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #00ffff;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-container">
    <div class="intro-container-text"></div>
    <div class="intro-container-img"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `min-height` and `display: inline-block`

check my code:

```css
.intro-container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: #fdee58;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.intro-container-text {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  float: left;
}

.intro-containter-img {
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #00ffff;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-container">
  <div class="intro-container-text"></div>
  <div class="intro-containter-img"></div>
</div>
```